# TypeError: Cannot read property 'getProtections' of null at doGet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm getting this kind of error,

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getProtections' of null at doGet

I tried to research it but I can't find anything about it. What seems to be the problem with this?

Here's my doGet code:

```
function doGet(e) {
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("MS_Q1");
const protection = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET)[0];
if (protection && protection.canEdit()) {
protection.remove();
}
return ContentService.createTextOutput("Sheet unprotected!");
}
```

Here's the name of my sheets:
[image: Picture]

Comment: Change `SpreadsheetApp.getActive` to `SpreadsheetApp.getActive()`

Comment: @Marios still getting the same error

Comment: Check if you have a sheet with the exact name of `MS_Q1` careful with caps or extra spaces.

Comment: @Marios The name `MS_Q1` is correct.

Comment: share a screenshot of your spreadsheet with the sheet names to be visible. I insist that you don't have a sheet with the name `MS_Q1`. You might have `MS_q1` or `MS Q1` or `MS_Q1 space` or whatever else.

Comment: @Marios I updated the question above with the screenshot.

Comment: I really can't reproduce the error. It works for me. Could you share a copy of your file? remove all the sensitive information.

Comment: @Marios that's okay. Maybe someone else can help me with this. Anyway, thank you for trying. :)

Comment: one more try, replace this `const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("MS_Q1");` with this: `const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()[1];` and let me know if it works.

Comment: @Marios same error :(

Comment: Is the a space in the sheet name string

Comment: @Cooper there is no space in the sheet name.

Comment: Well it works for Marios so I'd say try it in a fresh spreadsheet.

Comment: I can't reproduce this either, works for me. Are you sure the script is bound to the sheet? I.e. when you created the script, was it via the Sheets UI - Tools > Script Editor? Or did you create a script from drive or script.google.com?

Comment: @iansedano I used this `Sheets UI - Tools > Script Editor`

Comment: After this line `const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("MS_Q1");` Can you try running `Logger.log(sheet)` to be sure that its this assignment that is failing. Can you post a screenshot of your executions page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope below given code will solve your problem.

```
function doGet(e) {
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("MS_Q1");  
  const protection = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET)[0];
  if (protection !== null && protection.canEdit() == true) {
    protection.remove();
  }
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("Sheet unprotected!");
}
```